# Triggering macro with keyword typed into cell and enter key pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple worksheet search macro, FILTER_SHEET, that is tied to a command button using the keyword in cell c2. It works fine but I'd like to trigger the search when the user presses the enter key after typing the keyword. I can't figure out how to make the worksheet_change event work. I've searched and tried using the answers I found for similar problems on SO. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnKey "~", "recordEnterKeypress"
End Sub

Public enterWasPressed As Boolean
Sub recordEnterKeypress()
   enterWasPressed = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If enterWasPressed = True And Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
Call FILTER_SHEET
End If
enterWasPressed = False
End Sub
```

Apparently this does nothing.

Comment: Check your spelling (`Application` instead of `Applicaiton`). Also, `&` is the concatenation operator rather than a logical `And`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You show us something that is not working... why it is not working? any debug? any error?

Comment: I did mistype it for this post. The code was correct. Changing the "&" to "And" didn't change the behavior. Although I didn't know the difference. Thanks for that. I'll edit the post to correct the mispelling.

Comment: There is no error thrown and pressing enter does nothing. Debug shows within the Worksheet_Change procedure the value of enterWasPressed as <out of context>. whatever that means.

Comment: What happens if the user presses the **`Tab`** key? do you still want the UDF triggered? or the user simply types the **keyword** and clicks on another cell.. should that trigger the UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the ENTER pressed? Or just certainty that the user changed the value of C2 into "keyword" and exited the cell (by using ENTER, TAB, arrows, etc)?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing And Range("C2").Value = "keyword" Then
Call FILTER_SHEET
End If
End Sub
```

Paste this code onto the sheet that you want your "keyword" to be used in. Like so:
https://pasteboard.co/IGmX6Df.png

Comment: Yeah It would be better for any exit of the cell to trigger the filter. I commented out the Workbook_Open(), recordEnterKeypress() subs and edited the Worksheet_Change event as described but nothing happens when I exit the cell. It just moves the active cell. When I watch the change event, the debug tells me that 'keyword' value is <out of context> with an 'empty' Type. keyword is a public string declared in module 2 along with my other variables.

Comment: So this problem is resolved! I was putting the Private Sub into the module and not into the MS Excel Object/Sheet1. Also had to use the variable keyword and not the literal string "keyword".  Thank you all so much!!!!

Comment: Glad it this works for you @Chris H.! Please select the answer as "answer" and welcome again on SO!